# How to select a row that has a column with the minimum value from a subset of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of events' outcome probabilities from different bookmakers, `odds(id, event_id, bookmaker_id, market_id, value)`, from where I want to select the lowest odd for all markets.
I came up with

```sql
SELECT * FROM odds WHERE value IN (SELECT MIN(value) FROM odds GROUP BY market_id)
```

But that's wrong because the `IN` filter may compare values that does not belong to the current row.

Comment: The question appointed as "original" does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM odds o
WHERE o.value = (SELECT MIN(o2.value) FROM odds o2 WHERE o2.market_id = o.market_id);
```